# Show that sequence of antiderivatives has a subsequence that converges pointwise

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, sequence-of-function

I have this question from a real analysis assignment,

For $n\geq1$, let $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with $$|f_n(x)|\leq 1+\frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}$$

Define $F_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ via $$F_n(x)=\int_0^xf_n(t)dt$$ Show that the sequence $\{F_n\}_{n\geq1}$ admits a subsequence that converges pointwise on $[0,1]$.

My first thought is that each $f_n$ is uniformly bounded (by 2, for instance), but this doesn't seem like a strong enough conclusion to reach from that first line, considering the bound is shrinking as $n$ grows.

My second thought is that for fixed $x$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(x)|\leq 1$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}|F_n(x)|\leq x$ , which seems like it would be useful, but I'm not sure if it's relevant or how to use it.

I'm also not sure how to approach actually obtaining a pointwise convergent subsequence. I've seen results from class that give a sequence with uniform convergence, but not pointwise. So, I'm assuming there isn't some theorem to invoke to reach our conclusion? Should I try and construct some sort of subsequence myself?

Any hints or tips would be much appreciated. (apologies if there's already a question like this, I spent quite a bit of time searching and couldn't find anything)

Comment: Do you have access to Arzelà-Ascoli?

Comment: @ElchananSolomon yes, we do!

Comment: You don't have uniform bound right? You have only $|f_n(0)|\le 1+n$.

Comment: Great, because this is a very Arzelà-Ascoli flavoured problem. You need to show uniform boundedness and uniform equicontinuity to get a uniformly convergent subsequence.

Comment: @ElchananSolomon I see, I hadn't even considered that because I was too focused on the pointwise convergence. So once you use Arzela-Ascoli on the  subsequence $f_{n_k}$'s, say they converge uniformly to $f$, we can use the uniform convergence to pass the limit inside the integral right? That is, for fixed $x$ we have $$\lim_{k\to\infty} F_{n_k}(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^xf_{n_k}(x)dx=\int_0^x \lim_{k\to\infty}f_{n_k}(x)dx=\int_0^x f(x)dx$$

Comment: @ArcticChar you are right, I'm just not sure how to deal with this. The $f_n$'s are uniformly bounded on compact subintervals not containing 0, so I feel like there is some way around this, but I'm not sure yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, $\{F_n\}$ is uniformly bounded since

$$ |F_n(x)| \le  \int_0^x \left(1+ \frac{n}{1+(nt)^2} \right) dt\le 1 + \int_0^1 \frac{n}{1+(nt)^2} dt= 1+ \arctan n \le 1+ \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

But $\{ F_n\}$ might not be equicontinuous (see the remark  below).

To get around this, as you have pointed out in the comment, on each interval $[1/m, 1]$, $\{ F_n|_{[1/m, 1]|} \}$ is equicontinuous since $F'_n = f_n$ is uniformly bounded there. Using Arzela-Ascoli on each $[1/m,1]$ together with a diagonal sequence argument, there is a subsequence $\{F_{n_k}\}$ so that $\{F_{n_k}\}$ converges uniformly in $[1/m, 1]$ for all $m\in \mathbb N$. In particular, $F_{n_k}$ converges pointwisely in $(0,1]$. Lastly, since $F_n(0) = 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, the subsequence $F_{n_k}$ converges pointwisely in $[0,1]$.

**Remark** Take for example $f_n(x) = 1+ \frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}$. Then
\begin{align}
F_n(x)  &= \int^x_0 \left(1+ \frac{n}{1+(nt)^2} \right) dt \\
&= x + \arctan (nx) .
\end{align}

In particular, $F_n(1/n) = 1/n + \arctan 1> \arctan 1$. Thus choosing $\epsilon_0 = \frac 12 \arctan 1$, there is no $\delta >0$ so that
$$ |F_n(x) - F_n(0)| = F_n(x) < \epsilon_0$$
for all $x\in [0,\delta)$ and for all $n$. Thus $\{ F_n\}$ is not equicontinuous.

Comment: Sorry if I am wrong, but wouldn't the diagonal argument only work on a countable set though?

Comment: Yes, so the intervals are $[1/m,1]$ with $m\in \mathbb N$. @summeratlas

Comment: Ah yes sorry I misinterpreted that